# Call one event on a set of matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do what something like:

```
$('div > img').onAll('load', function() { alert('Loaded!') })
```

Which would alert "Loaded!" only once

I don't want this:

```
$('div > img').on('load', function() { alert('Loaded!'); });
```

because this would call the event after every single image has been loaded

Is there any ready function in jQuery that calls an event on a set of matches? Or do I have to write a custom function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own method

```
$.fn.onAll = function(ev, callback) {
    var xhr = [];
    this.each(function() {
        var def = new $.Deferred();
        var ele = document.createElement(this.tagName.toLowerCase());
        ele['on'+ev] = function() {
            def.resolve();
        }
        ele.src = this.src;
        xhr.push(def);
    });
    $.when.apply($, xhr).then(callback);
    return this;
}
```

to be used as

```
$('div > img').onAll('load', function() { alert('Loaded!'); });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mPKV/2/)

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there is a way without additional functions but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $images = $("div > img")
    , imageCount = $images.length
    , counter = 0;

    // one instead of on, because it need only fire once per image
    $images.one("load",function(){

         // increment counter everytime an image finishes loading
         counter++;
         if (counter == imageCount) {

             // do stuff when all have loaded
             alert('Loaded!'); 
         } 
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) {

            // manually trigger load event in
            // event of a cache pull
            $(this).trigger("load");
          }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
$('body').on('load','div > img',function() { alert('Loaded!') });
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: In your opinion body is a descendant of img? :)

Comment: @user2394156:   sorry i forgot to inter change the selectors